# Ionic Not Compiling Until Recompiled 3 Times

Tags: html, ionic4

I have created an ionic app and it has stopped compiling successfully first time.

First Time i compile it I get an error :
"localhost/:1 Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:8100/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
localhost/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
,and the screen shows 'Cannot GET'. The error was as follows:

[image: 1st Compile]

When I make a change to my code and recompile the code (comment out a random line of code)This is the error I get:
"Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'LoginPageModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

And I get a white screen.

[image: 2nd Compile]

When a undo the changes I have just done(i.e uncomment the random line I had previously commented). Recompile it the app finally compiles successfully.

[image: Third Compile]

tsconfig.json:

```
{"compileOnSave": false,
```

"compilerOptions": {

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "es2015",
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "dom"
]
```

},

"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}

Comment: It's hard to tell you anything without any errors or logs. You should check the output of your IDE and post it here. It's also discouraged to post pictures of problems as they wont be found later on when somebody searches for this problem.

Comment: This is the error after first compile "localhost/:1 Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:8100/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

localhost/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: The photos do not explain much but they were simply an addition to the explanation, as some prefer to see the problem.

Comment: I don't think it's cause of the favicon I also have this error (the favicon error, in my case it's not important). For me sometimes the typscript compiler does not compile properly. what are you using for compiling your files or pack it?

Comment: Visual Studio Code. Using ionic serve command

Comment: Have you tried removing gthe node_modules folder and run ` npm install --save`

Comment: Yes, just tried it again there, still same output.

Comment: If your using typescript can you share your tsconfig.json?

Comment: I have updated question with tsconfig.json

Comment: why is this `compileOnSave": false` false?

Comment: Was just default, it does compile when i save it however which is strange.